# Instagram application does not open with Android Intent

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-intent, instagram

This is my code, the thing is I don't want to send images I just want the IG app to open. Yes the app is installed but still it is not getting picked up.

This was working fine till last week. Please help.

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://instagram.com/");
            Intent insta = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
            insta.setPackage("com.instagram.android");

            if (isIntentAvailable(insta)) {
                this.startActivityForResult(insta, REQUEST_CODE_MY_PICK);
            } else {
            }

private boolean isIntentAvailable(Intent intent) {
        final PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
        List<ResolveInfo> list = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
        return list.size() > 0;
    }
```

Comment: Your code will not work on Android 11 without a `<queries>` element in your manifest. `ACTION_VIEW` does not return a result, so `startActivityForResult()` is not a good choice. There is no requirement for Instagram to support the insecure `http` scheme. And, you probably should be logging a message and/or letting the user know what is happening in your `else`.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback @CommonsWare .. yes I am providing feedback to user in the else .. I tried all of this .. still no difference

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this

```
Uri appUri = Uri.parse("https://instagram.com/_u/user_name");
Uri browserUri = Uri.parse("https://instagram.com/user_name");

try{ //first try to open in instagram app
  Intent appIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.instagram.android");
  if(appIntent != null){
     appIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
     appIntent.setData(appUri);
     startActivity(appIntent);
  }
}catch(Exception e){ //or else open in browser
   Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, browserUri);
   startActivity(browserIntent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace `Uri.parse("http://instagram.com/")` with `Uri.parse("https://instagram.com/")`. Also try to remove the `isIntentAvailable` and just call `startActivity(insta)` without 'forResult' and lastly remove `insta.setPackage` line.

Comment: it opens IG on the web browser .. I want the app to open

Comment: Check the settings "Open by default" of the IG app (in android app settings). 'Open supported links' must be set to 'Open in this app'. Also try to chabge the Uri to `https://www.instagram.com` - note the www.