# Open another application from my own intent

Tags: java, android

Here is the code but its not working :(
Please could anyone help me.

```
public class ActivitySettingsWifi extends Activity {

    public final void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {

        super.onCreate(bundle);

        try {

            bundle = new Intent("com.instagram.android");

            bundle.addFlags(268435456);

            startActivity(bundle);

        } catch (Bundle bundle2) {

            bundle2.getStackTrace();

        }

        finish();

    }

}
```

If i use any activity like android.settings.WIFI_ACITVITY
then its working but i want to open Instagram.

Comment: have you tried: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62914025/instagram-application-does-not-open-with-android-intent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to add the queries element to your manifest. For example:

```
<queries>
     <package android:name="com.instagram.android" /> 
</queries>
```

More info here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/queries-element

Here is your original code with a different method to launch the Instagram app. I also changed the catch block because it contained errors, but you can modify it to suite your application's needs.

```
public class ActivitySettingsWifi extends Activity {

    public final void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {

        super.onCreate(bundle);

        Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.instagram.android");

        try {
    
            startActivity(LaunchIntent);

            finish();

        } catch (Exception e) {
       
            finish();

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: How to implement this with my code please I'm dumb

Comment: I will edit my original answer to show the code.

Comment: Working code example is now in my answer above. You'll still need to add the <queries> element to your Android Manifest for it to work. Hope that helps, let me know if you have other questions.